# MATLAB file to Scilab conversion

Tags: scilab

I am converting a MATLAB file to SCILAB by using application icon and MATLAB to SCILAB translator, but I get a file.cat which I could not open it. Please can you help me to solve this problem or inform me how can I convert any MATLAB file to a SCILAB file in a proper way.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Dr.mark. Which Scilab version are you using? The latest 6.1.1 one?

Comment: I ask the question, because there are major changes in the converter from the 6.1.0 version to the 6.1.1 one. So the answer depends on the version.

Comment: Hi S. Gougeon, thank you for your reply. I am using the latest version 6.1.1 and I am a newcomer to Scilab from MATLAB.

Comment: So please first have a look to https://bugzilla.scilab.org/16823 ; fix this issue for your own Scilab installation (may be there is no issue if you run Scilab not on Windows) ; re-run mfile2sci ; and report your results for your case.

Comment: https://bugzilla.scilab.org/16823 : the how-to is described @ https://bugzilla.scilab.org/16823#c4

Comment: @S.Gougeon I look forward to Scilab production migrating to Github eventually so we can send pull requests and integrate these sorts of issues immediately.